# Excel VBA - Formula Counting Unique Value error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate the count of Unique values based on a condition.

For example,

For a value in column B, I am trying to count the Unique values in Column C through VBA.

I know how to do it using Excel formula -

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((B2:B12<>"")*(A2:A12=32)/COUNTIF(B2:B12,B2:B12))
```

that value for 32 is dynamic - Programmatically I am calling them inside my vba code as Name

This is my code :

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((rng <> "") * (rng2 = Name) / CountIfs(rng, rng))
```

This is the sample data with the requirement

[image: DATA]

Alternatively, I Concatenated both the columns for keeping it simple and hoping to identify the Unique values which starts with name* method.

I don't know where I am going wrong. Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: When you call a worksheet function from VBA all arguments must be passed comma separated as a ParamArray. What you are trying to do, of course, is passing nested worksheet functions, CountIfs within Sumproduct. I suspect it can actually be done, but it is so complicated that I never found interest in learning how to do it. It would be preferable over comparable VBA functions only when the database is quite large.

Comment: That's `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes but I am still struck in this - How do you identify the count of Unique values in a column which starts with say - John ?

Comment: That's a different problem altogether - one that your question does not describe. Please [edit] your question so that it can be answered appropriately - see [mcve].

Comment: Yes @Mat'sMug I edited my question now Sir as an alternative method. I believe that will reduce the complexity of the work but still I am struck with a formula for that. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of small data set and let us know the desired output based on that?

Comment: @sktneer Sorry for the late reply. I have added the sample data now as an Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Function GetUniqueCount(Rng1 As Range, Lookup As String) As Long
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
x = Rng1.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If x(i, 1) = Lookup Then
        dict.Item(x(i, 1) & x(i, 2)) = ""
    End If
Next i
GetUniqueCount = dict.Count
End Function
```

Then you can use it like below...

```
=GetUniqueCount($A$2:$B$10,C2)
```

Where A2:B10 is the data range and C2 is the name criteria.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added another screenshot. It returned the correct output.

Comment: It worked Sir. My mistake. Sorry, I had a typo in the data.

Comment: No problem. :) Glad it worked for you. Please take a moment to accept the solution to mark your question as Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the values into an array, create a temporary 2nd array and only add values to this array if they are not already present, and then replace the original array. Then it's just a simple matter to sum the unique values:

```
Sub Unique

dim arr(10) as variant, x as variant
dim arr2() as variant

for x = 1 to 10 ' or whatever
   arr(x) = cells(x, 1) ' or whatever
next x

arr2 = UniqueValuesArray(arr)

' now write some code to count the unique values, you get the idea

End Sub
```

---

```
Function UniqueValuesArray(arr As Variant) As Variant()

Dim currentRow, arrpos As Long
Dim uniqueArray() As Variant
Dim x As Long

arrpos = 0
ReDim uniqueArray(arrpos)

For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
    If UBound(Filter(uniqueArray, arr(x))) = -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve uniqueArray(arrpos)
        uniqueArray(arrpos) = arr(x)
        arrpos = arrpos + 1
    End If
Next x

UniqueValuesArray = uniqueArray

End Function
```

Comment: It throws an error saying. Cannot assign to an array ! I am trying to debug this.