# Excel VBA - Collection error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a collection and take the Count of Unique Values from that Collection but am getting an error in building a Collection itself. Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong. Kindly Share your thoughts. Please let me know how to find out the COUNT of UNIQUE VALUES as well.

```
Sub trial()

Dim sampleVisualBasicColl As Collection

For i = 2 To 10

    Rng = Range("M" & i).value

    StartsWith = Left(Rng, 3)

    If StartsWith = "Joh" Then

            sampleVisualBasicColl.Add Rng

    Else

    End If

Next

Debug.Print (sampleVisualBasicCol1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just noticed - isn't this pretty much a duplicate of what you asked yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314311/excel-vba-formula-counting-unique-value-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a collection you can just add Joh to the collection and then count the items:

```
'Using a collection
Sub Col_test()

    Dim cCol As Collection
    Dim i As Long

    Set cCol = New Collection

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To 20
            If Left(.Cells(i, 13), 3) = "Joh" Then
                cCol.Add .Cells(i, 13).Value, .Cells(i, 13).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Debug.Print cCol.Count

    On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 457 'This key is already associated with an element of this collection
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Col_test."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Sub
```

If you want the count of each item (Joh, Ben... whatever else you have) then use a dictionary:

```
'Using a dictionary.
Sub Dic_Test()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim key As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To 20
            If Len(.Cells(i, 13)) >= 3 Then
                sValue = Left(.Cells(i, 13), 3)
                If dict.exists(sValue) Then
                    dict(sValue) = dict(sValue) + 1
                Else
                    dict(sValue) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    For Each key In dict.keys
        Debug.Print key & " = " & dict(key)
    Next key

End Sub
```

**Note:**  I'm using `Cells` within the code rather than `Range`.  `Cells(2,13)` is M2 (13th column, 2nd row).

I find this link very helpful with dictionaries: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

As a further update (*after answer accepted*) and using the lists you gave in your question here:  [Excel VBA - Formula Counting Unique Value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314311/excel-vba-formula-counting-unique-value-error) this code with dictionaries will return `Joh = 4, Ian = 3`

```
'Using a dictionary.
Sub Dic_Test()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim dictFinal As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim keyFinal As String

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictFinal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Get the unique values from the worksheet.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To 20
            If Len(.Cells(i, 13)) >= 3 Then
                sValue = .Cells(i, 13).Value
                If dict.exists(sValue) Then
                    dict(sValue) = dict(sValue) + 1
                Else
                    dict(sValue) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'Count the unique values in dict.
    For Each key In dict.keys
        keyFinal = Left(key, 3)
        If dictFinal.exists(keyFinal) Then
            dictFinal(keyFinal) = dictFinal(keyFinal) + 1
        Else
            dictFinal(keyFinal) = 1
        End If
    Next key

    For Each key In dictFinal.keys
        Debug.Print key & " = " & dictFinal(key)
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: @Dareen Bartup-Cook Thanks for the hand. But I am looking for Unique Counts. Not the Counts. Unique for John alone. Say JohnRed,JohnRed,JohnBlue,JohnGreen then the Unique for John will be 3.

Comment: Ah, ok.... so JohnRed counts as 1.  Count the "Joh" but combine the exact duplicates.

Comment: Yes Sir. That's were I am struck. How to combine the exact duplicates? or to delete the duplicates programmatically,

Comment: I've updated the Collections code to include an error handler and use the full text in the cell as a key.  The key in a collection can't be repeated - it will throw err #457 if you try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the collection as well as declaring it.

```
Sub trial()

Dim myCol As Collection

Set myCol= New Collection ' creates the collection

For i = 2 To 10

    Rng = Range("M" & i).value

    StartsWith = Left(Rng, 3)

    If StartsWith = "Joh" Then

            myCol.Add Rng

    Else

    End If

Next

For each x in myCol
   Debug.Print x
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: No, This doesn't get me the collection as well. Debug.Print gives me the empty result

Comment: For one thing you can't print a collection like that, you need to specify which index you want to print. For another it wasn't liking the name of your collection for some reason. Try the amended code above, tested & working.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this code will help u since it's collecting Unique values in Listbox,,

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cUnique As Collection
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim vNum As Variant

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").Value ="John". End(xlDown))

Set cUnique = New Collection

On Error Resume Next

For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
Next Cell

On Error GoTo 0

For Each vNum In cUnique
Me.ListBox1.AddItem vNum

Next vNum
End Sub

Comment: `Set Rng = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").Value ="John". End(xlDown))` won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

You have not declared Variable Rng & i these are the most important thing to do. Meanwhile I would like to suggest this Formula,,

=Sum(if(Frequency (if(Len(B2 :B20) >0,Match(B2 :B20, B2 :B20, 0),""),if(Len(B2 :B20) >Match(B2 :B20, B2 :B20, 0),"",))>0,1))

Its Array formula so finish with Ctrl +shift +enter.

You can use this one also,

Sub CountUnique()Dim i, count, j As Integer count = 1 For i = 1 To 470 flag = False If count

> 1 Then For j = 1 To count If Sheet1.Cells(i,
>   3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(j, 11).Value Then flag
>   = True End If Next j Else flag = False End If If flag = False Then Sheet1.Cells(count,
>   11 ).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value count = count + 1 End IfNext i Sheet1.Cells( 1 ,
>   15 ).Value = count End Sub

Comment: No, I don't think this will work as you haven't added the Condition that is - Starts with "Joh" only

Comment: Sorry it was my fault,, I have not noticed the Criteria, meanwhile you use the Formula, soon I'll be able to get solution.